# Reading both string and integer from a text file

Tags: c, string, scanf

Let say I have a file looks like this

```
51.41 52.07 52.01 51.22 50.44 49.97 Coal Diggers
77.26 78.33 78.29 78.12 77.09 75.74 Airplane Flyers
31.25 31.44 31.43 31.09 31.01 30.92 Oil Fracting and Pumping
52.03 12.02 12.04 22.00 31.98 61.97 Big Bank
44.21 44.32 44.29 43.98 43.82 43.71 Rail Container Shipping
93.21 93.11 93.02 93.31 92.98 92.89 Gold Bugs
```

I want to read this file word using fscanf to put the numbers in float arrays and words in an array of strings. But, after few hours of strenuous thinking, I still can't figure out how to resolve this thing.

```
void dataInsert (COMPANY* company1, COMPANY* company2, COMPANY* company3, COMPANY* company4, COMPANY* company5, COMPANY* company6)
{
//Function Declaration
FILE* spData;
float number;
char* name[20];

//Statement
if ((spData = fopen("dataFile","r")) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR OPENING!!");
    exit (1);
}

int i = 0;
int numCount = 0;
int lineCount = 0;
while (fscanf(spData, "%f", &number) != EOF)
{
    if(isdigit(number))
    {
        if (lineCount == 0)
        {
            company1 -> stock_price[i] = number;
        }
        else if (lineCount == 1)
        {
            company2 -> stock_price[i] = number;
        }
        else if (lineCount == 2)
        {
            company3 -> stock_price[i] = number;
        }
        else if (lineCount == 3)
        {
            company4 -> stock_price[i] = number;
        }
        else if (lineCount == 4)
        {
            company5 -> stock_price[i] = number;
        }
        else if (lineCount == 5)
        {
            company6 -> stock_price[i] = number;
        }

        numCount++;
        i++;
        if (numCount == 6)
        {
            lineCount++;
            numCount = 0;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}//while
fclose (spData);
}//dataInsert
```

I don't know what to do with strings at the end of each line. I want to put those string in structure company -> name[10]. Those data are in a text file.

Comment: Are you sure you want to read the values as _integers_ and not _floating point_? Also, please show us [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Are those actual `<br>` tags in the file?  Is this file XML or HTML or something?  Maybe you should use a parsing library?  If the file is exactly the format you show here, you can parse it with C, but a scripting language would be easier... Python would be my choice.

Comment: Is your file always organized like that? With the same number of numbers before the string? Or do you have to detect whether what you're reading is a number or string?

Comment: scanf is not a very robust way to read a file, because if the formatting is changed even somewhat it will fail.

Comment: @Douglas B. Staple Then what do you recommend?

Comment: As an alternative, you could use a scripting language like Python to read the file and output it in a well-defined format like JSON.  Then use a JSON library in your C program to read in the data.  But I don't think it is that hard to just parse the input; my answer shows how to handle the string that you find after the float values.

Comment: `fscanf()` will return 0 if you have not reached EOF but the input didn't work as a float value.  Your code will try to read the company names as float values and you will get some sort of nonsense value.  You should save the value returned by `fscanf()` and check to see if it is equal to 1; if so, keep the value; if not, see if it is EOF or 0 and handle the situation accordingly.

Comment: I suggest reading one line at a time with fgets and then parsing the lines using separate tools like strtok, atoi, and so forth.  Scanf is really an ancient way to read a file; don't introduce it into new programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is in exactly that format, you can use `scanf()` easily.  Here's some code to get you started; I haven't tested this and you need to fill in a few missing things.

```
#include <ctypes.h>  // for isspace()
#include <stdio.h> // for scanf(), getchar(), and EOF

char c2d[MAX_LINES][MAX_LENGTH_STRING_PER_LINE];
char *pstr;
float f2d[MAX_LINES][6]; // 6 floats per line
float *p;
int c, current_line_number;
char ch;
FILE *input;

input = fopen(...);
if (!input)
    ... handle the error

for (current_line_number = 0; ; ++current_line_number)
{
    // handle each line of input

    // first read 6 float values
    p = f2d + current_line_number;
    c = fscanf(input, "%f %f %f %f %f %f", p + 0, p + 1, p + 2, p + 3, p + 4, p + 5);
    if (c != 6)
        ... handle the error here

    // next grab string; stop at '<' or end of line or EOF
    pstr = c2d + current_line_number;
    for (;;)
    {
        ch = fgetc(input);
        if (ch == EOF || ch == '<' || ch == '\n')
        {
            *pstr = '\0';
            break;
        }
        *pstr++ = ch;
    }
    if (ch == '<')
    {
        // char was '<' so throw away rest of input line until end of line
        for (;;)
        {
            if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n')
                break;
            ch = fgetc(input);
        }
    }
    for (;;)
    {
        // eat up any white space, including blank lines in input file
        if (ch == EOF || !isspace(ch))
            break;
        ch = fgetc(input);
    }
    // once we have hit end of file we are done; break out of loop
    if (ch == EOF)
        break;
}

fclose(input);
```

I didn't use `scanf()` to read the string at the end of the line because it stops when it hits white space, and your string values have spaces in them.

If the input file isn't always six float values, you will need to write code to call `scanf()` one float at a time until you hit something that doesn't parse as a float, and you will need to make the array of floats wide enough to handle the largest number of floats you will permit per line.

Good luck.

Comment: `fscanf` is to be used instead of `scanf`, right? The input is not from stdin, it is from a file.

Comment: Sure, and `fgetc()` instead of `getchar()`.  I changed the answer.

Comment: If I use scanf, does it just skip the strings at the end of each line?

Comment: According to the man page for `scanf()`, the format code `%s` reads any sequence of characters that is non-white-space, and then stops when it hits white-space.  Since the company names can have spaces in them, I thought it was easier to just loop until done rather than try to get `scanf()` to do what we want.  When you use `scanf()` with the `%f` format code, it will return a 0 to signal that the input didn't work as a float, and you will have some nonsense value in the float... probably a 0 or garbage, I haven't checked.  You can try it if you like.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `fscanf` I would recommend using `fgets` to get the line. Then use `sscanf` on that line to get the numeric values, and search for the first alphabetic character to know where the string starts (using e.g. [`strspn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn)).

Something like this:

```
char line[256];

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
{
    /* Get the numbers */
    float numbers[6];
    sscanf(line, "%f %f %f %f %f %f",
        &numbers[0], &numbers[1], &numbers[2],
        &numbers[3], &numbers[4], &numbers[5]);

    /* Where do the numbers end... */
    size_t numbers_end = strspn(line, "1234567890. \t");

    /* And get the name */
    char *name = line + numbers_end;

    /* Do something with the numbers and the name */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, unfortunately, I can't use sscanf since this is part of a school assignment so I have to do it based on what I have learned in class.

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd Never be afraid of "thinking outside the box"... You could do two solutions, one following the assignment _to the letter_, and then list possible shortcomings followed by a solution that solves the assignment but without the shortcomings.

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd Not that I'm saying that my solution is without shortcomings in itself, all solutions have pros and cons, including mine.

Comment: Yeah, I always try to solve problems in numerous ways, although it is the not best solution. That is what makes programming so interesting and fun! haha