# Reading both strings and integers from a file

Tags: c

I'm reading in a text file where certain lines begin with an asterisk, then other lines contain numbers indicating the size of a rectangle. I'm very confused on how I should be extracting this information though. I'm initially trying to use `fgets()` to read the strings and then `sscanf` to read the integers, as seen;

```
   while(fgets(line, MAX_CHARS, infile) != NULL) {
        if(line[0] == '*') {
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
        sscanf(line, "%d%d", &height, &width);
        printf("height: %d, width: %d\n", height, width);
    }
```

but it's printing like this;

*Case #1

height: 0, width: 0

height: 10, width: 20

....

*Case #2: Shape

height: 10, width: 20

height: 7, width: 7

....

Should I be reading this file character by character instead?

Sample input: (the height and width aren't updated right away)

```
 *Case #1
 10 20



   X            
    X           
  XXX           




 *Case #2: Shape
  7 7


    XX  
   XX   
    X
```

Comment: Providing an actual example of the input file would help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306314/reading-both-string-and-integer-from-a-text-file although the format of your file might be different.

Comment: try `else if(2==sscanf(line, "%d%d", &height, &width))
        printf("height: %d, width: %d\n", height, width);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, Thank you for the suggestion! What do you mean by `2` though? Is it suppose to be `line[2]`? Because I want to go to the next line, not just the second part of the first line if that makes sense.

Comment: It means that a successful read of the two numbers

Comment: the sscanf and final printf should be in a 'else' code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `else` part after the `if`.

```
while(fgets(line, MAX_CHARS, infile) != NULL) {
    if(line[0] == '*') {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    // Missing piece
    else {
       sscanf(line, "%d%d", &height, &width);
       printf("height: %d, width: %d\n", height, width);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right! I think because it was updating from the "case" lines but I didn't want that, I wanted to get the numbers from the second line, but I just assumed I was using the wrong `fgets` method, instead of just missing a simple `else` statement